# How to make Goalkeeper follow the football in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, game-engine

I am new to Unity3D game development. I am creating a penalty shootout game in Unity3D and I am using C# for the scripting. I have already created all the basic functionalities like kicking the ball, added 3D objects of the players and now I am working on goalkeeper animations to block the football. I have applied goalkeeper animations using mixamo. But I don't know what is the best approach to make goalkeeper dive in the direction of the football at the right moment.

Currently I am checking the displacement between football and goalkeeper in the `FixedUpdate()` as shown below in the sample code and at the particular displacement I start the animation of the goalkeeper in the left or right direction according to the displacement.

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    canAnimateGoalkeeper();
}

void canAnimateGoalkeeper() {

    distanceBetweenBallAndPlayer = Vector3.Distance(football.transform.position, goalKeeper.transform.position );

    if(!isFootballAtInitialPosition && (distanceBetweenBallAndPlayer <= 10f)) {
            //if football is in the left side of the goalkeeper
            goalKeeperLeftDiveAnim();

            //else if football is in the right side of the goalkeeper
            goalKeeperRightDiveAnim();
    }
}
```

Comment: Arguably too broad sadly.  Maybe ask this over at http://gamedev.net.  There you will find brilliant articles; tutorials and forums.  Happy game making!

Comment: @MickyD Thanks I'll ask it there

Comment: Do you need a trigger for the ball shooting event or you need help to decide in which part to dive?